# why doesn't `\;` given a new linebreak in algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e

Here is minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\nextnode}{\ensuremath{\text{Next}}}
\newcommand{\intree}{\ensuremath{\text{InTree}}}


\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{}
\KwResult{}
asdf\;
$\nextnode[r] \leftarrow nil$\;
$\intree[r] \leftarrow true$\;
\caption{}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

With the output:

[image]

I am expecting line breaks, but it just doesn't happen.

Why?

Comment: `\;` is just a spacing command.  Are you thinking of `\\\`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'm not sure. In this [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithm2e_package), `\;` gives the line break.

Comment: You are right, the package gives a new meaning to this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded the `algorithm2e` package with the `algo2e` option.  This changes the name of the environment to `algorithm2e`.  Using that name works as expected:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\nextnode}{\ensuremath{\text{Next}}}
\newcommand{\intree}{\ensuremath{\text{InTree}}}


\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
\KwData{}
\KwResult{}
asdf\;
$\nextnode[r] \leftarrow nil$\;
$\intree[r] \leftarrow true$\;
\caption{}
\end{algorithm2e}

\end{document}
```